# Same push notification displayed twice

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification

I keep getting the same push notification twice in the notification list. The iOS is 10.2. Registration for push has been done only once.  I tested the push using "easy APNs provider" and it successfuly shows the push once. However, when the actual push comes from server it repeats twice. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool { registerPushNotifications() } 

func registerPushNotifications() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let settings = IUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settin‌​gs)
  }
}
```

Comment: :- Please share some code

Comment: Once ask your backend developer to check the push sending code. May be from backend push getting added twice on websocket.

Comment: Make sure your device token is exist only once in db. Recheck in your server.

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        registerPushNotifications()
  
        }

Comment: @Dyana please share your registerPushNotification full code. you are using?

Comment: @ViralNarshana  do i need to check it with the back end?

Comment: @YogendraGirase  func registerPushNotifications() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            
        }
    }

Comment: Yes. check with backend.

Answer (score 0):

You have registered it twice thats why
Check this call `registerForRemoteNotifications()`

Comment: I think he is ok on it, mentioned by him that from APNs getting the push once. or anything else?

Comment: There are only two possible cases 
1. Either twice registration or 
2. Duplicate APNs

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal   registerForRemoteNotifications()  is called only once.

Comment: how can i check for duplicate APNs?

Comment: Just Print UserInfo dictionary in didReceiveNotificationResponse see its is coming once or twice consecutively?

Comment: its coming only once: [AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "Your message Here";
}]

Comment: then its a twice registration issue are you using any 3rd party notifcations SDK or apple Native?

Comment: m using apple native